# can we use 'entered' without 'into'

Tags: grammar

The Bank entered into an agreement with X.
The Bank entered an agreement with X.

I have always found 'entered into' being used but does the modern usage allow omission of 'into'?

Comment: I enter rooms all the time, and enter characters into text fields like this one. Is your issue with usage regarding *agreements* solely?

Comment: As Chasly suggests, there is an ambiguity when "into" is omitted in the above context.  If this document has any sort of legal importance it's probably best to avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

> The Bank entered an agreement with X.

The problem with this in my opinion is that it encroaches on a different usage of 'to enter'.

> 7  to make report of (a ship or its cargo) to customs authorities
>
> 8 to place in proper form before a court of law or upon record (enter a writ)
>
> 9 :  to go into or upon and take actual possession of (as land)
>
> 10 :  to put formally on record (entering a complaint)
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enter)

Without context to the contrary I would naturally tend to think that 'the Bank entered an agreement with X'  followed definitions 8 or 10.

**However**

It is clear from this [Google ngram: enter into an agreement,enter an agreement](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enter%20into%20an%20agreement%2Center%20an%20agreement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Center%20into%20an%20agreement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Center%20an%20agreement%3B%2Cc0) that there is a gradual increase taking place in the usage you suggest - and indeed a reduction in the more traditional version.

Comment: I concur in this impeccable analysis.